# How to change the time in Apache IoTDB to timestamp format?

Tags: timestamp, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Currently, the "time" column of Apache IoTDB looks like "2023-02-08T11: 25:15.953+08:00". Is there any way to make the time here displayed as a timestamp?

I checked the official document, and it only says that the time can be displayed as `Long`
type, but no example of this change can be found. Anyone can tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display timestamps or other readable formats, you can add the parameter `-disableISO8601` to the startup command of Apache IoTDB. For example: `$IOTDB_CLI_HOME/sbin/start-cli.sh -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6667 -u root -pw root -disableISO8601`.